# Why does toArray() duplicate elements on subsequent subscribe?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, reactivex

I have following code that takes 3 lists  of objects (Location, Machine, Sensor). They are then mapped based on parent ids (Location has machines and machine has sensors) to object with children 
The resulting observable return object that is Location (that has list of Machines, where each has list of Sensors).
It works fine. However I'd like to get a single list of Locations, but when I use toArray() on the observable, the original array that is returned is duplicated with each subscription.

```
function getLocations() {
  return [
    {id: 'loc1', name: 'Some location'},
    {id: 'loc2', name: 'Other location'},
    {id: 'loc3', name: 'New location'},
  ];
}
function getMachines() {
  return [
    {id: '1', name: 'Machine 1', location: 'loc1'},
    {id: '2', name: 'Machine 2', location: 'loc1'},
    {id: '3', name: 'Machine 3', location: 'loc2'},
    {id: '4', name: 'Machine 4', location: 'loc3'},
  ];
}
function getSensors() {
  return [
    {id: 's1', name: 'Sensor 1', machine: '1'},
    {id: 's2', name: 'Sensor 2', machine: '3'},
    {id: 's3', name: 'Sensor 3', machine: '1'},
    {id: 's5', name: 'Sensor 5', machine: '4'},
    {id: 's4', name: 'Sensor 4', machine: '2'},
  ];
}

const sensors$ = Rx.Observable.from(getSensors());
const machinesWithSensors$ = Rx.Observable.from(getMachines())
                                             .flatMap(machine => sensors$.filter(sensor => sensor.machine === machine.id).toArray().map(sensors => {
                                               return {...machine, sensors: sensors}
  }));

const allData$ = Rx.Observable.from(getLocations())
                                  .flatMap(location => machinesWithSensors$
                                    .filter(machine => machine.location === location.id)
                                    .toArray().map(machines => {
  return {...location, machines: machines};
}));
const allDataArr$ = allData$.toArray();
allData$.subscribe(s => console.log('allData1', s))
allData$.subscribe(s => console.log('allData2', s))
allData$.subscribe(s => console.log('allData3', s))
allDataArr$.subscribe(s => console.log('allDataArr1', s))
allDataArr$.subscribe(s => console.log('allDataArr2', s))
allDataArr$.subscribe(s => console.log('allDataArr3', s))
```

Example on codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ooaBdj

Why is that? How do I 'reset' the observable before each subscription?

Comment: What behavior would you like to see exactly?  Should the second and third subscriptions get no data?

Comment: I would expect the same array each time. Actually I believe it's a regression, as in 5.4.3 this returns the same array as expected.